# How to get the output node name of a saved model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

For a tensorflowjs-convertor, to run the command one of the argument is output_node_name.
so what should be output_node_name or how can we find it?

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_node_names=' ' \
    /saved_model \
    /web_model
```

Comment: What format are you trying to convert the model to?

Comment: I am trying to convert a frozen or keras  model to a web model,

Comment: Frozen_Model is deprecated by tfjs converter. Could you share the model structure from the pb file?